# Error with badge_icon in MDIcon Kivy Python

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I cant use *badge_icon* MDIcon from this [documentation](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/label/?highlight=badge#mdicon-with-badge-icon). And this is the source that I used to use. What happened?

```
MDNavigationLayout:
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager

        Screen:
            name: "scr 0"
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                BoxLayout:
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Screen 0"
                        halign: "center"
                    MDIcon:
                        icon: "git"
                        badge_icon: "numeric-10"
```

And the result of this source code is like this.

[image: The git icon don't have badge_icon]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for being stupid; I am using the 0.104.2 version, not the latest. This feature only works in the newest version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).